# How to skip ext-all.css effect to be apply on Extjs panel html content

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I added a div's innerHTML in Extjs panel through **panel.body.update('innerHTML(Content)')**. After add innerHTML Extjs panel shows it's HTML with having some css effects & I think it is due to ext-all.css (Extjs style library.)

So my question is how can I show the html as it is in it's div. For example If I set the div's innerHTML in htmleditor it's working fine with it's original view.

Answer (score -1):

You can maybe the css class with `cls`, i.e. with `cls : ''`.